# Sprites not drawn at assigned positions

Tags: c++, multithreading, 2d, sprite, sfml

I have a simple multithreaded 2D program that tries to draw a 16 x 16 sprites/tiles view where each tile is 32x32 pixels big.

First, in the main thread, I create instances of a class for each tile, each holds a sprite:

**Tile.h**

```
class Tile
{
    Point2D pos;
    public:
    Point2D getPos() { return pos; }
    sf::Sprite getSprite() { return sprite; }
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    Tile(int _x, int _y, int _type);
    ~Tile();
};
```

**World.cpp constructor**

```
    for (size_t y = 0; y < WORLD_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < WORLD_WIDTH; x++) {
         tiles.push_back(Tile(x, y, 0));
    }
}
```

**Tile.cpp**

```
Tile::Tile(int _x, int _y, int _type) {
pos = Point2D(_x, _y);

sprite.setTexture(world->rm->dirt); 
sprite.setPosition(world->TILE_WIDTH * _x, world->TILE_HEIGHT * _y);
```

}

Everything seems to be fine this far, and indeed when I printed out all the values here the values were as I expected, where `_x` and `_y` are increments of 1 as they come from the loop, and `sprite.setPosition()` gets increments of 32, such as 0, 32, 64, etc. passed as parameters.

After this view is initialized, the sprites are then drawn in a different thread:

**main.cpp**

```
void renderingThread(sf::RenderWindow* window) {

// the rendering loop
while (window->isOpen()) {
    window->clear();
    for (size_t y = 0; y < world->WORLD_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < world->WORLD_WIDTH; x++) {
            window->draw(world->tiles[y * x + x].sprite);
        }
    }
    window->display();
}
}
```

Here, the values have become weird resulting in a view like this: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYb1RtxJEu8bGRRaEFORHY2enM/view?usp=sharing

Resetting the sprite's position in rendering loop before drawing had no effect:

```
world->tiles[y * x + x].sprite.setPosition(world->tiles[y * x + x].getPos().x * 32, world->tiles[y * x + x].getPos().y * 32);
```

Am I missing something simple here or what is going on? I can't find anything myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `y * x + x` for the tile index is certainly wrong. It should likely be `y * width + x`.